# How do I find out if bot and user are on the same server?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I tried the codes in a couple of opened help requests here, but I couldn't get the result I wanted. What I want is if the bot and the user are on the same server, I want it to send a message to the console, if not, I want it to send a message that it is not guinea.

I tried code like this:

```
const serverid = "serverid "
const userid = "userid "
const server = client.guilds.cache.get(serverid)
if (server.members.cache.find(userid)) {
console.log("I am on the same server as this user.")
} else return console.log("I am not in the same group as this user!")
```

but it didn't

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation of Client](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client), `client.members` doesn't even exist. But assuming it does, mind that bots might only know of **online** users *(or at least users that were recently online)*.

You can iterate over the guilds your bot is in and use `await guild.members.fetch(userId)` (see [this](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=members) and [this](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch)). This will even find offline users, so basically allowing you to check if someone is part of that guild, *assuming you're in it yourself*.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing `server.members.cache.find(userid)` with `server.members.cache.get(userid)` if you are using id or just use `server.members.cache.find(u => u.id == userid)`